# Check whether function series is convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the following task: Check whether given function series is pointwise convergent, uniformly convergent or "almost" uniformly convergent (*id est* $f, f_{n} : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $ \forall_{a, b \in I} (f_{n} \downarrow _{[a;b]}) $ uniformly convergent to $ (f \downarrow _{[a;b]}) $.

*I use $ \downarrow _{[a;b]} $ to say that function is cut to range $[a;b]$.*

Function series: $ \sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x}, x \in [0;+\infty) $

I have found that limit of sum argument ($n \rightarrow +\infty$) is equal 0. Is it enough to say yes, yes and yes?

Comment: No, that is not enough. If you remove the $(-1)^n$, the limit of the sum argument is still $0$, but that series diverges.

Comment: Hint: sum by parts.